# convert the pages of a pdf into images using aws lambda and s3

Tags: image, pdf, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, imagemagick

I am using AWS S3 for storing the pdf and lambda for running my functions. Recently I came across a need in which I want to convert the pdfs that are just uploaded on S3 into different images for each page. The images will be clubbed into a brand new folder created on the S3 bucket. I have almost checked everything on the internet but none of them is capable to do so.

A tool named imageMagick could help but I don't know how to implement it on lambda.

preferred language: Node.js (Optional)

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you want to create images? What is wrong with the PDF files as they are? Did you try using ImageMagick at all? You can run command line tools on Lambda.

Comment: @Ryan Actually I am delivering hand-written notes to the students of our college in the form of PDFs till now. But the reason behind not to go further with PDF is that first of all it take a whole lot of time to load. Suppose there is a PDF file with about 50 pages all those pages include a image of one particular side of notebook each. The PDF would cost me around 16 to  20 MBs at least and at same time one image of the notes would cost around 800 KBs which will take less time of course. What I am going to do is displaying image in a scroll view with lazy-loading. I hope you will understand.

Comment: Assuming your PDF files are text heavy, I would recommend converting to PNG, which is well supported in browsers. JPEG will leave compression artifacts around text. The difference in file size of the images should be less important than the quality difference I bet.

Comment: C:\Users\HP\Desktop\notex\Final PDF>magick VBIV6.pdf VBIVF/VBIV6images.jpg............................ The following command I want to execute, would you please help me out, as how to write a function for lamda in node or any language in which you are comfortable. @Ryan

Comment: any update on this?